# A very simple problem on 1-cocycles

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, class-field-theory

Edit: According to the comment of Mindlack this special question is solved, but yet I have no idea if my calculations lead to another number $r\neq 0$. And in the case $r\neq 0$, I don't know how should I continue.

---

---

---

I have a very simple question about **1-cocycles** $\Big( f(\sigma\tau)=\sigma f(\tau)+f(\sigma) \Big)$: Let $G:=Gal(\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q})$, and I denote the identity automorphism by $\sigma_0$. Is my following conclusion correct?

$$f(\sigma_{0}\sigma_{0})=\sigma_{0}f(\sigma_{0})+f(\sigma_0) \Longrightarrow 
f(\sigma_{0})=\sigma_{0}f(\sigma_{0})+f(\sigma_0) \Longrightarrow 
\sigma_{0}f(\sigma_{0}) =0 \Longrightarrow 
f(\sigma_{0}) =0, $$

but $\mathbb{Q}(i)^{\times}$ does not have $0$. What is wrong with my calculations?

Comment: $+$ refers to the group law of the group your cocycle is valued in. So in $\mathbb{Q}(i)^{\times}$ (apparently) it’s the field multiplication, and $0$ is the neutral element of the group so is the field’s “1”.

Comment: @Mindlack Ok, this solves this problem, but my general problem is not solved yet. Here I can see that the neutral element $0$ will be changed into $1$, but I don't have any idea what is the suitable $x$, that will be changed into $i$? Because (according to Hilbert 90 theorem) I guess there are some computations of cocycle that should lead to $i$.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking. What are “some computations of cocycle”? What does “lead to $i$” or “be changed into $i$” mean? The Hilbert 90 theorem says that a $\mathbb{Q}(i)^{\times}$-valued cocycle on $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q})$ is of the form $g \longmapsto \frac{g(x)}{x}$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Q}(i)^{\times}$.