# Another question on 1-cocycles (explicite computation of 1-cocycles)

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, class-field-theory

I want to calculate 1-cocycles, as they are described in Neukirch's Class field theory. In what follows the Galois group of $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is acting on $L^{\times}$.

The first comment in this question, answers my question (but it doesn't answer the "Edited version"): [A very simple problem on 1-cocycles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4353585/a-very-simple-problem-on-1-cocycles)

But now I have another question, actually I did something but I don't know how much of it is correct, and my question is kind of proof-verification or solution verification.

Let $D < 0$ be a discriminant, and consider the imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$, and its Galois group $G:=Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})/\mathbb{Q})=\{\sigma_0, \sigma_1 \}$, where $\sigma_0$ is the identity automorphism, and $\sigma_1$ is the complex conjugation ($\Big(\sigma_1(\sqrt{D})=-\sqrt{D}\Big)$. Now, I want to calculate **1-cocycles** $\Big( f(\sigma\tau)=\sigma f(\tau)+f(\sigma) \Big)$ in this case. By the same way, as described in that question, we have:

$$f(\sigma_{0}\sigma_{0})=\sigma_{0}f(\sigma_{0})+f(\sigma_0) \Longrightarrow 
f(\sigma_{0})=\sigma_{0}f(\sigma_{0})+f(\sigma_0) \Longrightarrow 
\sigma_{0}f(\sigma_{0}) =0 \Longrightarrow 
f(\sigma_{0}) =0, $$

and as it is mentioned in the first comment there: $f(\sigma_0)=0$ (which is $1$), and nothing is new. Now I want to calculate $f(\sigma_1)$, and **my question starts here** (is my conclusion right? And how can I finish it?):

$$f(\sigma_{1}\sigma_{1})=\sigma_{1}f(\sigma_{1})+f(\sigma_1) \Longrightarrow 
f(\sigma_{0})=\sigma_{1}f(\sigma_{1})+f(\sigma_1) \Longrightarrow 
0            =\sigma_{1}f(\sigma_{1})+f(\sigma_1),  \ (\star\ calculation)$$

now suppose $f(\sigma_1)=a+b\sqrt{D}$,
$$0            =\sigma_{1}f(\sigma_{1})+f(\sigma_1) \Longleftrightarrow 
0=(a-b\sqrt{D})+(a+b\sqrt{D}) \Longleftrightarrow 0=2a \Longleftrightarrow a=0,$$

or equivalently $f(\sigma_1)=b\sqrt{D}$. **And here I stopped and I am not able to continue. Are my calculations correct? I think it is not correct, but then how can I calculate $f(\sigma_1)$? I have too many doubts about what I am going to write here**: $f(\sigma_1)=b\sqrt{D}$, and we have to switch into $e^{\theta\sqrt{D}}=\cos(\theta\sqrt{-D})+i\sin(\theta\sqrt{-D})$, and then what? For which values of $\theta$ we can say $\cos(\theta\sqrt{-D})+i\sin(\theta\sqrt{-D}) \in \mathbb{Q}^{\times}(\sqrt{D})$?

But it seems very unusual and weird to me, and I think I am doing big mistakes, but **I don't have any idea how to calculate $f(\sigma_1)$. Are my "$\star$ calculations" true?**

---

---

---

Edit: The correct form of calculations after the answer by **Ted** (thanks to the answer by Ted, now I feel much better):

$$f(\sigma_{0}\sigma_{0})=\sigma_{0}f(\sigma_{0}).f(\sigma_0) \Longrightarrow 
f(\sigma_{0})=f(\sigma_{0}).f(\sigma_0) \Longrightarrow 
f(\sigma_{0}) =1, $$
and also

$$f(\sigma_{1}\sigma_{1})=\sigma_{1}f(\sigma_{1}).f(\sigma_1) \Longrightarrow 
f(\sigma_{0})=\sigma_{1}f(\sigma_{1}).f(\sigma_1) \Longrightarrow 
1            =\sigma_{1}f(\sigma_{1}).f(\sigma_1),  \ (\star\star \ calculation)$$

now suppose $f(\sigma_1)=a+b\sqrt{D}$,
$$1            =\sigma_{1}f(\sigma_{1}).f(\sigma_1) \Longleftrightarrow 
1=(a-b\sqrt{D}).(a+b\sqrt{D}) \Longleftrightarrow 1=Norm(a+b\sqrt{D}),$$

So we can say that $f(\sigma_1)=a+b\sqrt{D}$, where $a^2-Db^2=1$. Also for any rational solution of $a^2-Db^2=1$, there is a 1-cocyle $f$, with $f(\sigma_1)=a+b\sqrt{D}$.

Comment: Yes, you have now correctly determined all the cocyles.

Comment: @Ted Thanks for your patience and kindness, dear Ted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clarify what module $G$ is acting on: is it the additive group, or the multiplicative group, of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ ?  If it is the multiplicative group, then your calculations are wrong because the operation in the cocycle identity should be multiplication instead of addition: $f(\sigma \tau) = \sigma f(\tau) \cdot f(\sigma)$.

In Hilbert's Theorem 90, $G$ is acting on the multiplicative group.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifying, I think I understand the point. I edited my question, and I added the edited version of my calculations at the end of my question. Could you please have a look at them? I think, now my calculations are right. Did I finish correctly?

Comment: You shouldn't change the question like that, @Tirelessandhardworking. If you have a new question, ask it in a new post.

Comment: @Shaun I had so much doubt, also I guessed that the answer by Ted answered my question. Also, I felt it was immoral to ask what I thought was right (about the same question and answer) in the form of another question. So I edited my question and described the answer by Ted there. I wrote that it is an "edit", and I felt it doesn't change the soul of my question. Also that edit makes it easier for who will read this question in the future (to understand the concept in the right way, just if she/ he had the same problem as mine)